# Open Data Reader Must Be Closed and a Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting an Open Data Reader error. I figure it's in the foreach loop, but I'm not sure how to replace it and still achieve my goal, although it's obviously not working right now. The error is coming in on the "_context.SaveChangesAsync();" in the loop.

I need to read/copy from the first db call into the second db call inside the loop.
Unless there is another way to do this.

I do NOT want to use MARS as proposed in many other questions, although in this particular situation I could probably get away with it. I would much prefer to edit my existing code to perform the desired effect without triggering the error.

```
//first add one
        var xOne = _context.PostOnes.First(m => m.OneZero == zero);
        ClonePost one = new ClonePost();
        one.PostNumber = xOne.OneZero;
        one.Type = "1";
        one.ItemNumber = xOne.OneId;
        one.ItemData = xOne.OneStag + "_"+ xOne.OnePart + "_" + xOne.OneTitl;
        _context.Add(one);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //add 4 in loop
        foreach (PostFou postFou in _context.PostFous.Where(m => m.FouZero == zero))
        {
            ClonePost fou = new ClonePost();
            fou.PostNumber = postFou.FouZero;
            fou.Type = "4"; ;
            fou.ItemNumber = postFou.FouId;
            fou.ItemData = postFou.FouDigit + "_" + postFou.FouType + "_" + postFou.FouName + "_" + postFou.FouPhon + "_" + postFou.FouEmai + "_" + postFou.FouAddr
                + "_" + postFou.FouLocality + "_" + postFou.FouAdminDistrict + "_" + postFou.FouPost + "_" + postFou.FouOrg + "_" + postFou.FouChec;
            _context.Add(fou);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        ////add 5 in loop
        //foreach(PostFiv postFiv in _context.PostFivs.Where(m => m.FivZero == zero)) 
        //{
        //    ClonePost fiv = new ClonePost();
        //    fiv.PostNumber = postFiv.FivZero;
        //    fiv.Type = "4";
        //    fiv.ItemNumber = postFiv.FivId;
        //    fiv.ItemData = postFiv.FivPrio + "_" + postFiv.FivCode + "_" + postFiv.FivText;
        //    _context.Add(fiv);
        //    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //}
```

The error details:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, string transactionName, bool shouldReconnect)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, string transactionName)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginDbTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransactionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable<ModificationCommandBatch> commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList<IUpdateEntry> entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AURA.Controllers.CloneController.ReviewClone(string zero) in CloneController.cs
+
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot use the foreach loop in this situation, as it is leaving the db connection open while in the loop.

I used the following as a workaround to the problem. Identifying the relevant records, putting such records into a List, then iterating through the list to fill the new table.

```
List<int> fouIds = _context.PostFous.Where(m => m.FouZero == zero).Select(n => n.FouId).ToList();
        
        foreach(var id in fouIds)
        {
            PostFou postFou = await _context.PostFous.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FouId == id);
            ClonePost fou = new ClonePost();
            fou.PostNumber = postFou.FouZero;
            fou.Type = "4";
            fou.ItemNumber = postFou.FouId;
            fou.ItemData = postFou.FouDigit + "_" + postFou.FouType + "_" + postFou.FouName + "_" + postFou.FouPhon + "_" + postFou.FouEmai + "_" + postFou.FouAddr
                + "_" + postFou.FouLocality + "_" + postFou.FouAdminDistrict + "_" + postFou.FouPost + "_" + postFou.FouOrg + "_" + postFou.FouChec;
            _context.Add(fou);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
```

Comment: Seems like you could also just call `SaveChangesAsync` once after the loop completes to avoid all the db roundtrips.